# How to store data on different levels but referring to the same object

Tags: swift, xcode, oop, model-view-controller, struct

I've just finished my first app and got declined for a job. The good thing is: I've got comments on weak sides of my code. Due to my lack of experience I am having hard times even seeing a way of fixing it. The related part of code is:
Items.swift:

```
struct Items {
    let imageName: String
    let description: String
    var location = (0, 0)
    var collectedIndex = K.Values.notCollected
}
```

ViewController:

```
var chest = Items(imageName: K.icons.chest, description: K.descriptions.chest)
var key = Items(imageName: K.icons.key, description: K.descriptions.key)
var rock = Items(imageName: K.icons.rock, description: K.descriptions.rock)
var bone = Items(imageName: K.icons.bone, description: K.descriptions.bone)
var mushroom = Items(imageName: K.icons.mushroom, description: K.descriptions.mushroom)
var apple = Items(imageName: K.icons.apple, description: K.descriptions.apple)
    
var items = [Items]()
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
items = [chest, key, rock, bone, mushroom, apple]
```

What is bad about that:

1. "item location is created as Items' property. But an item can also be picked up or used. For these operations you don't need item's location. Therefore this data is excessive and only used in particular case. The same goes for collectedIndex. These properties should be located on another level"
2. "Fixed number of items that are created in advance in ViewController and accessed through vars of the ViewController is extremely poor decision that goes aside with all the principles of  good programming".

Further in my code I do need to assign location and collectedIndex to each item in order for everything to work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You already have an answer, but perhaps [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be better target audience for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, rename you struct as Item without "s" at the end. It isn't an array.
I'm not sure about the first case, maybe you don't need to store `location` and `collectedIndex` properties. In the second case, you had better not create var for each object, I mean

```
private var items = [Item]()

private func loadData() {
    items = [Item(imageName: K.icons.chest, description: K.descriptions.chest),
             Item(imageName: K.icons.key, description: K.descriptions.key),
             Item(imageName: K.icons.rock, description: K.descriptions.rock)
             Item(imageName: K.icons.bone, description: K.descriptions.bone),
             Item(imageName: K.icons.mushroom, description: K.descriptions.mushroom),
             Item(imageName: K.icons.apple, description: K.descriptions.apple)]
}
```

Comment: exactly what I needed regarding second case! Thanks a lot! I do need to assign location and collectedIndex to each item further on in order for everything to work.